# Cannot infer type for type parameter when deriving Deserialize for a type with a generic with a Deserialize trait bound

Tags: rust

I use a generic which is serializable and deserializable. However, there is an error on the `Deserialize` derive attribute telling that the type can not be inferred.

The compile error is thrown for both struct and enum. Commenting one of those will not resolve anything.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.104

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Jhon<A>
where
    A: Serialize + for<'a> Deserialize<'a>,
{
    foo: Foo<A>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Foo<A>
where
    A: Serialize + for<'a> Deserialize<'a>,
{
    A,
    B(A),
}
```

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:3:21
  |
3 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `A`
  |
  = note: cannot resolve `A: _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize<'de>`
  = note: required by `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize`
  = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:3:21
  |
3 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `A`
  |
  = note: cannot resolve `A: _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize<'_>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::de::Visitor<'de>` for `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::<impl _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize<'de> for Jhon<A>>::deserialize::__Visitor<'de, A>`
  = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:11:21
   |
11 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `A`
   |
   = note: cannot resolve `A: _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize<'de>`
   = note: required by `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize`
   = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:11:21
   |
11 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `A`
   |
   = note: cannot resolve `A: _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize<'_>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::de::Visitor<'de>` for `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Foo::<impl _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Jhon::_serde::Deserialize<'de> for Foo<A>>::deserialize::__Visitor<'de, A>`
   = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5cc3f0c99f5859141670f10e6356858d)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the trait bounds. It is also generally unadvisable to do so on structs. This code works:

```
#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Jhon<A> {
    foo: Foo<A>
}

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Foo<A> {
    A,
    B(A)
}
```

[Rust playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20serde%3A%3A%7BSerialize%2C%20Deserialize%7D%3B%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Serialize%2C%20Deserialize)%5D%0Astruct%20Jhon%3CA%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20Foo%3CA%3E%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Serialize%2C%20Deserialize)%5D%0Aenum%20Foo%3CA%3E%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20A%2C%0A%20%20%20%20B(A)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Hello%2C%20world!%22)%3B%0A%7D)

Serde automatically tries to determine the bounds on `Deserialize` and `Serialize` implementations when you use its `derive` macro implementation. To use custom bounds you need to tell Serde that you are doing this using the `#[serde(bound = "...")]` attribute.

```
#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "A: Serialize + for<'a> A: Deserialize<'a>")]
struct Jhon<A>  where A:  Serialize + for<'a> Deserialize<'a>{
    foo: Foo<A>
}

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "A: Serialize + for<'a> A: Deserialize<'a>")]
enum Foo<A>  where A: Serialize + for<'a> Deserialize<'a>, {
    A,
    B(A)
}
```

[Rust playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20serde%3A%3A%7BSerialize%2C%20Deserialize%7D%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Serialize%2C%20Deserialize)%5D%0A%23%5Bserde(bound%20%3D%20%22A%3A%20Serialize%2C%20for%3C%27a%3E%20A%3A%20Deserialize%3C%27a%3E%22)%5D%0Astruct%20Jhon%3CA%3E%20%20where%20A%3A%20%20Serialize%20%2B%20for%3C%27a%3E%20Deserialize%3C%27a%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20Foo%3CA%3E%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Serialize%2C%20Deserialize)%5D%0A%23%5Bserde(bound%20%3D%20%22A%3A%20Serialize%2C%20for%3C%27a%3E%20A%3A%20Deserialize%3C%27a%3E%22)%5D%0Aenum%20Foo%3CA%3E%20%20where%20A%3A%20Serialize%20%2B%20for%3C%27a%3E%20Deserialize%3C%27a%3E%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20A%2C%0A%20%20%20%20B(A)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Hello%2C%20world!%22)%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer given above, I should point out (since I ran into this myself today) that sometimes you already *have* the Deserialize bound satisfied in a supertrait the problematic type parameter, and this error represents serde trying and failing to supply its own (redundant) bound on that type parameter.

In that case you still want to use the `serde(bound)` attribute but with an *empty* bound: that is, annotate with `#[serde(bound = "")]`.

Comment: This was very helpful. But I still don't understand the underlying issue. The way you phrased it, this seems like a minor bug in `serde`. If not and I misunderstood the issue, is there something I can do to avoid this? Adding this empty bound directive everywhere seems like a sub-optimal solution.